# How to migrate from MySQLServer to BigData Hadoop

Tags: mysql, database, performance, hadoop, bigdata

I am using MySql Server database where that contains 500GB spaces so performance is very slow where it take 15-20mins to show search result. Please assist me what is the best solution to make search within seconds. can i use BigData Hadoop or anyother please assist me.

Thanks

Comment: What type of search operations you perform?? Can you elaborate a little on your queries.

Comment: Have you tried a `FULLTEXT` index?

Answer (score 0):

If query speed is important, look into column store databases. That can be either with or without hadoop.

With hadoop, it's important to choose the right file structure. Parquet is a popular option. Query these files with:

- Cloudera Impala
- Apache Drill

Without Hadoop:

- HP Vertica
- Amazon Redshift
- Greenplum

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS

Comment: Add Sphinx to the list.